# Cannot run Volttron Instance

Tags: volttron

I am working on Volttron and created a couple of agents.
Today all of a sudden volttron instance fail to start.
Earlier everything was working fine and I was able to start volttron and test the agents.

This is the error message i am getting now.

(volttron) nitin@346Z4Y2:~/volttron$ ./start-volttron

**Please execute from root of volttron repository.**

Earlier I was getting folllowing messages-

**(volttron) nitin@346Z4Y2:~/volttron$ ./start-volttron**

PID file exists but process is not running. Removing old
VOLTTRON_PID file

Please execute from root of volttron repository.

**(volttron) nitin@346Z4Y2:~/volttron$ vcfg**

volttron-cfg needs to be run from the volttron top level source directory

I don't know what happened suddenly that I cannot start the Volttron Instance.

Comment: The VOLTTRON_PID error mentioned happens when the program is killed without cleaning up.  Is it possible your computer went to sleep or you shut down the program without shutting down your system?  Start/stopped wsl?  These are all possible things that could have happened to make this happen.  What version of wsl are you using 1/2?  Which version of linux?

Comment: It seems some directory was missing due to to which this was happening.
After I copied the missing files/dir it started running again.
Issue fixed. 
@Craig Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed after copying missing volttron files.
@Craig Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue was created when transferring a copy of the repository from one instance to another.  The user missed a vital directory.  Lesson learned from this is to clone a fresh new copy of VOLTTRON or make sure you get all of the directories when copying from one system to another!